# Why isn't Scala used much for Desktop Applications?

Tags: scala

I have been hearing a lot about Scala being used for web development but I hear very little things about Scala being used for Desktop Applications. Is it true that it's not used much for Desktop Applications? What are the reasons for this?

Comment: This question is probably better suited to programmers rather than stackoverflow because it's subjective.  FWIW, in my opinion the reasons would be much the same as why Java isn't used much for Desktop.  The platform independence didn't prove to be a big win.  Windows has such a large market share of desktop and the toolkits in Java for rich GUI are fairly leaky abstractions making them cumbersome.  You might as well go native and most serious desktop applications do.

Comment: Agreed. The real question is why Java is not used for desktop applications, there's nothing preventing you from using Swing from Scala (and I _think_ there's even an official Swing wrapper).

Comment: @Jiří Pospíšil: Yup. `scala.swing`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Scala is not used more for desktop applications exactly for the same reason java is not used more. And that is lack of good toolkits and frameworks for it. Sure you have swing, swt and others but they are not very sophisticated, and when you try to use them you feel like you went 10 years in the past.
The real question would be why are java desktop toolkits that bad, but that is out of the scope of this one. 
Simply one of the driving design principles of scala was to leverage the existing java libraries. And to the great extent scala has done that. Since java now lives mainly on server side apps and android (not on desktop) the has mainly the same fate.

This could change in the future, but i doubt it.

Comment: Java FX 2.0 still might be a viable alternative to use instead of non-Java tools, as it is a framework for making eye-pleasant and lightweight UIs using contemporary ideas in plain Java (or plain Scala).  Moreover, it will be a default UI framework instead of Swing in Java 8 (or 9).

Answer (score 9):

I think it's for the lack of tools. Often it's heard *choose the right tool for the job*, where the *tool* can be the platform, the framework, the operating system, or as in this case, the programming language.

There's nothing in Scala itself which prevents writing desktop applications. The point is  you **never ever write programs in a language**: you write programs **with a toolkit**. A toolkit is made of a language, libraries, and helper tools to glue everything together. Scala is a nice language, and also inherits from Java some cool widgeting libraries, but there is no Scala framework for building a Desktop application.

So, even if nothing stops developers, there is nothing encouraging them, and that's why usually other platforms are chosen for Desktop development. It's often made the example of  [Tcl/Tk](http://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because the language is relatively new, its features can help mainly in developing app which deals with big and complex data (features common in functional prog. languages) or already developed framework is helping in writing web application.

There are not big advantages in using scala for normal "desktop" apps in comparison with languages like C++, java,... But of course, after some time there will be more developers coding in scala and also more various standard desktop scala apps.